# Angular JS Unit testing: how to test function in service that doesn't return

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm sorry for possible duplicate, I didn't find any solution for my problem.

I'm need to write tests for a service in Angular JS app.

So I have one main function that returns and uses as an external method. And a couple help functions for external. So how can I call and test things inside help functions (`subFunc`)?

service.js

```
function TestService() {
  return {
    mainFunc: mainFunc
  };

  funcion mainFunc() {
    //do some and call subFunc()
    subFunc(a)
  }

  function subFunc(a) {
    if (a === 1) {
      // ... magic 1
      return true;
    } else {
      // ... magic 2
      return false;
    }
  }
}
})()
```

service.spec.js

```
describe('Test Service', function() {
  beforeEach(module('TestService'));
  var TestService;

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
      TestService = $injector.get('TestService');
  }));

  it('should return true if subFunc called with 1', function () {
    // ....
  });
})
```

Comment: You don't have to redesign your code to accommodate your test. I'm certain the "requirement" is to provide test _coverage_ of your API. If you test `mainFunc()` correctly and thoroughly, then those tests will provide _coverage_ for `subFunc()`. In this case, with this design, the unit of code is the combination of `mainFunc()` and `subFunc()` together. There is nothing wrong with that idea and your goal can be achieved. There is a pedantic view of this and a practical one. You'll get opinions about both here.

Comment: Well, look at your contrived code please. `subFunc()` returns a Boolean that `mainFunc()` never does anything with. If you want direct answers to code questions - provide code that does something. Besides, I don't know what _here_ and _where_ means.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite TestService to expose `subFunc` so that you can stub it with a spy and track whether it was called.

That is one of the reasons you write tests before and while writing the code: they will influence the style of the code so as to make it easier to test. In this case `subFunc` has to be externally visible to allow easy testing so make it visible.